# Как экранировать кавычки,апострофы и остальные вредные символы которые могут все испортить?

Tags: laravel, шаблонизаторы

Использую шаблонизатор blade. Вот кусок кода:

```
@extends('layouts.org')
@section('name', $book->name)
```

в layoute пишу

```
<input type="text" value="@yield('name')">
```

Если в названии книги встречается кавычка, то рушится структура HTML. Можно было бы заменить кавычки атрибута на апостроф, но в тексте так же может встречаться и апостроф.

Какие есть средства чтобы избежать таких ситуаций?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете экранировать ещё при формировании section:

```
@section('name') {{$book->name}} @endsection
```

Или при выводе использовать код PHP:

```
<input type="text" value="<?= e($__env->yieldContent('name')) ?>">
```

Ответ взят отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33901279/272885